# WriteConcern.Acknowledged vs new WriteConcern { Journal = true, W = 1 }

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm a bit confiused about WriteConcern settings in mongodb c# driver.

Does WriteConcern.Acknowledged means Journal= true and FSYNCED =true?

If I just want to be sure it writes to primary, is WriteConcern.Acknowledged enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no C# programmer however by semantics alone I would say - no, it is not.

Journal and Fysncing a write is very much different to acknowledging its existance in a certain `mongod`, honestly both set at the same time is pointless since you are effectively waiting for it to write to the disk twice `:/`.

You would be better to just go with Journal; if you need journaled writes that is. Again Journaled writes are different to acknowledged writes, Journaled gives a sense of persistance on disk BEFORE the response is returned, however, an acknowledged write merely requires to be received in order for it to return, not written to disk.

So no, `WriteConcern.Acknowledged` is not the same as your old setting of `Journal= true and FSYNCED =true` however I would say it is enough and that you was probably going overkill with those settings.

#### Edit

I noticed your title has the setting `W = 1` in it. This is not Fsync but instead `acknowledged`. So all you need to do to get the same writes as you did before is to actually add a journal option to your write concern along with `WriteConcern.Acknowledged` and that should give you the same write concern as you did before.

Comment: if i want to be sure about my writes to primary. and i set w to 1 and set journal true... it is the enough thing? and is it true when i use Acknowledged i can't be sure if it is journalled?

Comment: @SerdarBuyuktemiz Yes, using acknowledged you cannot be sure it is journalled, only using the added journalled option can you

Answer (score 2):

`WriteConcern = Acknowledged` only means that the primary has received the write operation. There is no guarantee that data is written to disk before your write call returns. If you want to make sure data is written to disk on the primary node, then you need `journal=true` and `fsync=true`, which you can do in the connection string.

Comment: so new WriteConcern { Journal = true, W = 1 } is better on being more sure about the write then Acknowledged  ?

Comment: Yes it is. When the call returns you'll be sure data was written to disk.